# Determine list of event handlers bound to event

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, debugging, events

I have a WinForms form that won't close. In OnFormClosing, e.Cancel is set to true. I am guessing that some object in my application has bound to the Closing or FormClosing event, and is blocking the close. To find out, I'd like to determine what delegates are bound to one of these events.

Is there a way to determine the list of handlers bound to an event? Ideally I would do this via the Visual Studio debugger, but can write code in the application to find the handlers if necessary. Understanding that an event is like a hidden private field, I've navigated through the Debugger to the "Non-Public Fields" for the "Windows.Forms.Form" ancestor of my form, but to no avail.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In short, you're not meant to do this - but for debugging purposes...

An event is **often** backed by a private field - but not with controls; they use the `EventHandlerList` approach. You would have to access the form's protected `Events` member, looking for the object mapped to the (private) EVENT_FORMCLOSING object.

Once you have the `FormClosingEventHandler`, `GetInvocationList` should do the job.

---

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;
class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    { // assume we don't know this...
        Name = "My Form";
        FormClosing += Foo;
        FormClosing += Bar;
    }

    void Foo(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) { }
    void Bar(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) { }

    static void Main()
    {
        Form form = new MyForm();
        EventHandlerList events = (EventHandlerList)typeof(Component)
            .GetProperty("Events", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .GetValue(form, null);
        object key = typeof(Form)
            .GetField("EVENT_FORMCLOSING", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
            .GetValue(null);

        Delegate handlers = events[key];
        foreach (Delegate handler in handlers.GetInvocationList())
        {
            MethodInfo method = handler.Method;
            string name = handler.Target == null ? "" : handler.Target.ToString();
            if (handler.Target is Control) name = ((Control)handler.Target).Name;
            Console.WriteLine(name + "; " + method.DeclaringType.Name + "." + method.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same need; in `Control`, the identifying keys are named in fashion like `EventMouseDown` rather than `EVENT_MOUSEDOWN` as they are for `Form`.

Comment: For anyone who is trying this with a bunch of Windows controls and can't figure out why `CheckBox.CheckedChanged` and `CheckBox.CheckStateChanged` don't work, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/27413251/492

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that the form doesn't validate.

The `FormClosing` event is raised by the private `WmClose` method in `Form`, which initializes `e.Cancel` to `!Validate(true)`.  I haven't investigated, but in certain circumstances, `Validate` will always return `false`, causing the close to be canceled regardless of any event handlers.

To investigate this, enable [.Net source debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx), put a breakpoint in your `FormClosing` handler, go to the source for `Form.WmClose` (up the call stack), put a breakpoint at the beginning of `WmClose`, and close the form again.  Then, step through it in the debugger and see why `Validate` is returning `false`.  (Or which event handler is setting `e.Cancel` to true)

To solve the problem, set `e.Cancel` to `false` in your own handler.