# Listening for key strokes with C#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to listen for the arrow keys being pressed on a C# Application.

I have added the following method to listen for an arrow key being pressed and report each one, in the C# file of the XAML file:

```
private void Grid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Left)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("left");
    }
    if (e.Key == Key.Right)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Right");
    }
    if (e.Key == Key.Up)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Up");
    }
    if (e.Key == Key.Down)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Down");
    }
}
```

In the corresponding XAML, the Grid element begins as follows:

```
<Grid Background="Black" MouseWheel="Grid_MouseWheel"
    MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown" MouseUp="Grid_MouseUp"
    MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove" KeyDown="Grid_KeyDown">
```

Currently, the mouse-related listeners are functioning, but the keyboard one (KeyDown="Grid_KeyDown") is not. Do I need to add something else to make this work?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171396 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347724

Comment: I wonder how the `Console` window appears in a `WpfApplication`? Unless you are running a Console application and trying to show a Wpf Window, so looks like that's the problem. If it's a test, try using `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print` instead of `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: King, both methods of printing to debug/console seem to yield the same result, but maybe it does make more sense to write to debug.print.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your handler is never called is because the Grid itself handles the KeyDown event, and sets the flag to stop the event from bubbling further (to your application handler). What you can do is handle the `PreviewKeyDown` event instead. This gives you a chance to respond to the key down event before the Grid does.

In the XAML file, modify your Grid element like this:

```
<Grid Background="Black" MouseWheel="Grid_MouseWheel"
    MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown" MouseUp="Grid_MouseUp"
    MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove" PreviewKeyDown="Grid_PreviewKeyDown">
```

The actual code for the event handler is pretty much the same:

```
private void Grid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Key == Key.Left)
       Console.WriteLine("left");
    //  and whatever else you want to do here..
}
```

**NOTE** It's also important to ensure that the Grid is part of the logical focus scope. If not, and some other element has keyboard focus in a different tree, the Grid will not receive any events. See here for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Mike, thanks for your quick response. However, I tried making these changes and I still do not see any output on the console from pressing the arrow keys.

Comment: @Jake if you're still not getting the events, make sure the Grid is in focus. If another control had keyboard focus, they the Grid will not be receiving the keyboard events. I've just checked with a quick solution on my computer and it worked fine.

Comment: I'll  add that if you are wiring up to a KeyPreview event, and want to do more than just listen (I.e. some action if Key.Left) then you'll likely want to set `e.Handled = true` if you handle the action.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the **Focusable** property of the Grid to "*true*" because its "*false*" by default.

```
<Grid Background="Black" MouseWheel="Grid_MouseWheel"
MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown" MouseUp="Grid_MouseUp"
MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove" KeyDown="Grid_KeyDown"
Focusable="true">
```

Also, you dont have to click on the window every time you start the app if you give focus to the Grid after initialization:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        GridWindow.Focus();           
    }
```

I named the Grid "*GridWindow*".