# How to copy an EventHandler to another class of the same hierarchy

Tags: c#

We have a class `ModelBase` that has defined a PropertyChangedEventHandler `PropertyChanged`. Then we inherit from this class, and using kind of a decorator pattern, add more functionality to it -- filtering, inserting, etc. We wrap the current object into another one each time we add stuff to it and copy all the properties so we can use them in the next class.

```
public class ModelBase<T> : IModel<T> where T : IView, new()
 {
   ...
   ...
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   protected internal void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   {
     if(PropertyChanged != null)
       PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
 }

 public class ViewModel : ModelBase<Grid>, IViewModel
 {
  protected internal ViewModel(iewModel viewModel)
            : base(viewModel)
  {
     // Copy all the properties of viewModel to the ones of this instance
     ...
     ...   
     PropertyChanged = viewModel.PropertyChanged;

  }

 }
```

The issue is that when trying copy the `PropertyChanged` event handler the compiler throws the error `... can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= operator...`.

Is there a way how a can copy `PropertyChanged` property to the next decorator isntance?

Comment: See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660480/determine-list-of-event-handlers-bound-to-event - is this what you want to do?

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea.  Are you sure you want to clone event handlers?

Comment: You are doing something wrong. If the underlying object is a "living" one, that is, its properties may change and there are subscribers to its events, you can't do with a one-time clone: you need to catch the changes in the underlying object and reflect them in the wrapper object. If however your underlying object just contains the data, there have to be no event subscribers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field backing a field-like event is private; you can only access it within that class.

You could make a `protected` property in the base class that returns the delegate's contents:

```
protected PropertyChangedEventHandler ProeprtyChangedHandlers {
    get { return PropertyChanged; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
if (viewModel.PropertyChanged != null)
    this.PropertyChanged += viewModel.PropertyChanged;
```

Comment: The compiler keeps saying `... can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= operator...` with this.

Comment: OK, didn't test it.. as SLaks answer is correct guess it doesn't really matter anymore. :)