# Issue when trying to get the delegate associated to a Control's event

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection

I am trying to serialize controls to XML and I want to serialize their events' handler.

I am using this bit of code:

```
Control childCtrl = ....

if (childCtrl.GetType() == typeof(Button)) {
    EventInfo baseEventInfo = childCtrl.GetType().GetEvent("Click");

    EventHandlerList events =
        typeof(Control).GetProperty("Events",
                                    BindingFlags.Instance |
                                    BindingFlags.Public   |
                                    BindingFlags.Static   |
                                    BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(childCtrl, null)
                                      as EventHandlerList;
    object eventField = typeof(Control).GetField("Event" + baseEventInfo.Name,
                                                 BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                 BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(childCtrl);
    Delegate aDel = events[eventField];

    xmlSerialisedForm.WriteElementString("Click", aDel.Method.ToString());
}

if (childCtrl.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox)) {
    EventInfo baseEventInfo = childCtrl.GetType().GetEvent("CheckedChanged");

    EventHandlerList events =
      typeof(Control).GetProperty("Events",
                                  BindingFlags.Instance |
                                  BindingFlags.Public   |
                                  BindingFlags.Static   |
                                  BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(childCtrl, null)
                                    as EventHandlerList;
    //Error here: GetField returns null
    object eventField = typeof(Control).GetField("Event" + baseEventInfo.Name,
                                                 BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                 BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(childCtrl);
    Delegate aDel = events[eventField];
    xmlSerialisedForm.WriteElementString("CheckedChanged", aDel.Method.ToString());
}
```

Now I *know* that the checkbox has a handler bound for the event `CheckedChanged`; when using the debugger I can see that method in the `EventHandlerList`:

[image]

Now the same code actually works when dealing with a Button (when I want to get the delegate associated to the `Click` event). Why is it not working for the CheckBox? What am I missing here?

EDIT: my current workaround (very ugly) that I deduced from calling `GetFields` on `typeof(CheckBox)` and looking in the array:

```
if (childCtrl.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox)) {
    EventHandlerList events =
      typeof(Control).GetProperty("Events",
                                  BindingFlags.Instance |
                                  BindingFlags.Public   |
                                  BindingFlags.Static   |
                                  BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(childCtrl, null)
                                    as EventHandlerList;

    object eventField =
      typeof(CheckBox).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                 BindingFlags.Static)[0].GetValue(childCtrl);
    Delegate aDel = events[eventField];
    xmlSerialisedForm.WriteElementString("CheckedChanged", aDel.Method.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather infuriatingly, the `CheckedChanged` event seems to have been written in an entirely different fashion to the rest of the Events on the .NET framework. So was `CheckStateChanged`. Here they are.

```
typeof(CheckBox).GetField("EVENT_CHECKEDCHANGED",
      BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
      BindingFlags.Static| 
      BindingFlags.Instance | 
      BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
typeof(CheckBox).GetField("EVENT_CHECKSTATECHANGED", 
      BindingFlags.NonPublic |
      BindingFlags.Static|
      BindingFlags.Instance |
      BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
```

Just to make it more special, you can't treat everything as a `CheckBox` or those are the only two events you will get.