# Why I need the SqlCommandBuilder to update a table in Database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldataadapter, sqlcommandbuilder

I watched a video tutorial and reprogrammed the same code. I have noticed that a didn´t understand, why I have to use the SqlCommandBuilder for updating a table.

```
    SqlDataAdapter sda;
    SqlCommandBuilder scb;
    DataTable dt;

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);

        sda.Update(dt);
    }
```

I never use the variable *scb*. But when I comment out the `scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda)`, then I get an error message:

> "System.InvalidOperationException: A valid update command is required for an update."

Can someone explain, what function the CommandBuilder has?

In the remarks of the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0154tsb(v=vs.110).aspx) it says:

> The SqlCommandBuilder registers itself as a listener for RowUpdating events that are generated by the SqlDataAdapter specified in this property.

But I don´t understand when the CommandBuilder steps into action?

Comment: The SQL command need four queries for an update : Select, Update, Insert, Delete. The command builder take an existing Select query and creates the other three.

Comment: You don't need either. Most people use ORMs or SqlCommand to execute commands directly.

Comment: The `SqlCommandBuilder` just creates sql queries for select,update,insert and delete, and puts them into the `SqlDataAdapter` properties. You may not use it and do something like `sda.UpdateCommand.CommandText=<your query to update>`

Comment: @Pikoh In the debugger, updatecommand is null, even after execution of the sda.Update(dt); When exactly does it create the sql queries?

Comment: Well,you are right,i was trying to "simplfy" it. In fact, as the documentation says, it subscribes to the `RowUpdating` event of the `SqlDataAdapter` and it creates the other queries then

Comment: Anyway, i've never used it. In my opinion.it's better to add your own queries to have a better control.

Comment: @Pikoh thank you for the good explanation. It sounds very logical. Is there any file, like a designer, where i can see the subscription to the `RowUpdating` event?

Comment: I don't understand @Mr.Tambay. What do you want to see? Source code of `RowUpdating`? What handlers are subscripted to `RowUpdating` in runtime? Or what are the generated queries by `SqlCommandBuilder?

Comment: @Pikoh I want to see what handlers are subscribed to RowUpdating in runtime. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know why would you want to do that, but see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/660489/579895)